# How can I optimize JSON webscrape?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, optimization, bitcoin

I recently got interested in bitcoin and the whole blockchain thing. Since every transaction is public by design, I thought it would be interesting to investigate the number of wallets, size of transactions and such. But the current block height of bitcoin is 732,324 which is quite a lot of blocks to walk through one after each other. Thus, I want to obtain the hash code for each block so I can multi-thread grabbing the transactions.

Blockchain links one block after each other and if I go to the first block ([the genesis block](https://blockchain.info/rawblock/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f)) and simply find the next block in the chain and so forth until the end, I should have what I need. I am quite new in python, but below is my code for obtaining the hashes and saving them to a file. However, at the current rate it would take 30-40 hours to complete on my machine. Thus, is there a more efficient way to solve the problem?

```
#imports
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import json

#Setting start parameters
genesisBlock = "000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f"
baseurl = "https://blockchain.info/rawblock/"
i = 0 #counter for tracking progress

#Set HASH
blockHASH = genesisBlock

#Open file to save results
filePath = "./blocklist.tsv"
fileObject = open(filePath, 'a')

#Write header, if first line
if i == 0:
    fileObject.write("blockHASH\theight\ttime\tn_tx\n")

#Start walking through each block
while blockHASH != "" :

    #Print progress
    if i % 250 == 0:
        print(str(i)+"|"+datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

    # store the response of URL
    url = baseurl+blockHASH    
    response = urlopen(url)

    # storing the JSON response in data
    data_json = json.loads(response.read().decode())

    #Write result to file
    fileObject.write(blockHASH+"\t"+
                      str(data_json["height"])+"\t"+
                      str(data_json["time"])+"\t"+
                      str(data_json["n_tx"])+"\t"+
                      "\n")
                      
    #increment counter
    i = i + 1

    #Set new hash
    blockHASH = data_json["next_block"][0]

    if i > 1000: break #or just let it run until completion

# Close the file
fileObject.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't comment directly on the efficiency of your approach, using [orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson) or [rapidjson](https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/) will definitely speed up your results, since they're both quite a bit faster than the standard json library.

Rapidjson can be swapped in as easily as just doing `import rapidjson as json` whereas orjson you have to make a couple changes, as described on their github page, but nothing too hard.

Comment: Thanks, that helped somewhat. rapidjson improved speed with about 10%. So now my projection is 29 hours instead of 32 \o/